center megamenu div under nav button
I have used some code which I got from W3 schools to create a megamenu. I want the box to appear centred to the nav button selected, not centred to the whole page. I'm not really concerned about the mini view, it is full screen mode I am trying to set up. Everything else works fine apart from the alignment issue. My full code is here without the header code.


function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .icon {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 60%;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.navbar .dropdown>.dropdown-content {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 10px, 0);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar a:not(:first-child),
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.column a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
    background-color: #eff;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .navbar.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .column {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
<div class="line">
    <div class="s-12 l-12 center">
        <div class="navbar margin-bottom" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 1</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 2</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 3</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 1</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 2</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 3</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



I have tried targeting the .dropdown-content class mostly. It always seems to break the navbar which inserts the dropdown box inside the navbar instead of below the navbar.

Here is a quick fix if you want your mega menu centered relative to Dropdown you will need to add position relative to it and keep position absolute  for your div.dropdown-content (also remove overflow : hidden). You will need as well to give it a width in px (which may not be very responsive, you will have to watch this). Then you can use your translate and left to center it accordingly.


function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    /* overflow: hidden; */  /*--removed this*/
    display: flex;   /* added this*/
    height: 50px; /* added this*/
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .icon {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative; /*----added this*/
    float: left;
    /* overflow: hidden; */  /*---removed this---*/
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    /* width: 60%;*/ /*---removed this---*/
    /*left: 0; */ /*---removed this---*/
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /* z-index: 1; */ /*---removed this---*/
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/*----------added this-------------*/
.dropdown:hover div.dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 10px, 0);
    left: 50%;
    top: 40px;

}
/*----------------------------------*/

/* .navbar .dropdown>.dropdown-content { */  /*removed this*/
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* transform: translate3d(-50%, 10px, 0); */
/* } */

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{*/   /*---removed this---*/
    /* display: block; */
/* }  */

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar a:not(:first-child),
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.column a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
    background-color: #eff;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .navbar.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .column {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
<body>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="s-12 l-12 center">
            <div class="navbar margin-bottom" id="myTopnav">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="column">
                                <h3>Category 1</h3>
                                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <h3>Category 2</h3>
                                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <h3>Category 3</h3>
                                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="column">
                                <h3>Category 1</h3>
                                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <h3>Category 2</h3>
                                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <h3>Category 3</h3>
                                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>




It works! I have been going over it for weeks without any luck at all, and you solved it in minutes, I am getting old lol. Loved the way you showed the corrections in the code, that helps me understand where I was going wrong. Tips Hat to you

Thank you very much , very glad that it helps . Enjoy coding!

There is one small issue, it affects the react when resizing the screen, but I am sure I can fix that :-)

Yes this works for large screen for small screen it needs to be adjusted accordingly. I am sure you will be able to solve it

yup, I appreciate the time you took to help me. I should be able to do the rest from here. thanks again

You very welcome I am sure you will. Still if you need help I will bé glad to help if am able to

x.className += " responsive"; is an antipattern. And even bug-prone. Element.classList.toggle("someSpecialClass") is all you need (instead of 5 lines of really bad JavaScript)

Hi @Roko C. Buljan, thanks for your always good advices in JS, I did not change his JS fonction just modified his css part to center it. You are completely right for this JS using toggle() would have been much better

To center the megamenu div under the nav button in full-screen mode, we need to modify the CSS for the dropdown-content class. Here's how we can update the code:
.navbar .dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar .dropdown>.dropdown-content {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
}

These changes will center the megamenu div under the nav button. Here's a brief explanation of the modifications:

We added position: relative; to the dropdown class to establish a positioning context for the absolute positioning of the dropdown-content.
We removed the translate3d and replaced it with translateX(-50%) to center the dropdown content horizontally.
We changed the width to auto and added min-width: 100% to ensure the dropdown is at least as wide as the button, but can expand if needed.

These changes should center the megamenu under the nav button in full-screen mode while maintaining the existing functionality.


function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .icon {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.navbar .dropdown > .dropdown-content {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.column a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
    background-color: #eff;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar a:not(:first-child),
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .navbar.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .column {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
<div class="line">
    <div class="s-12 l-12 center">
        <div class="navbar margin-bottom" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 1</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 2</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 3</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 1</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 2</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <h3>Category 3</h3>
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Sujit, your code does not work, nothing shows when moving the mouse over the buttons

Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned
